# ButterKnife error while running TestCases in androidstudio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, butterknife

I have created one test case in androidTest folder as MyHomeActivityTest.Java
in 
     /app/src/androidTest/java/MyHomeActivityTest.java

And I have one HomeActivity.java class in 
     /app/src/main/java/HomeActivity.java

In my HomeActivity.java class i am using butterknife for view-injection. I am running the test cases for HomeActivity in MyHomeActivityTest.java.

But when i am running the test cases the tests are running fine but getting NoClassDefFound Error for butterknife.

My Project classes are

MyHomeActivityTest.java

```
public class HomeActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomeActivity> {
    private Solo solo;

    public HomeActivityTest() {
        super(HomeActivity.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
        getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testRun() {
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Home activity class",HomeActivity.class);
        final LinearLayout homeScreen =
                (LinearLayout) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.home_screen);
        assertEquals(View.GONE, homeScreen.getVisibility());
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:1.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
}
```

As soon i am running the MyHomeActivityTest class it's giving me NoClassDefFoundError since the super class of this is HomeActivity.class which is using butterKnife.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add ButterKnife Dependencies to your AndroidTest folder.

Comment: I tried to add the test dependencies in dependency folder like this androidTestcompile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'   but still no result ! same error